# Can we configure Twilio Flex's wrap up time?

Tags: sdk, twilio, twilio-flex

Is it possible to and how can we configure the wrap up time an agent sees after they end a call? At the moment, the agent has to manually "complete" a call. Is there any way we can time that out?

Answer (score 0):

My agents asked me to disable wrap up phase of task. Try to use Event call back of taskrouter workspace, and send task update events to tilio function. Then update task to closed state. If you need to set timeout - keep in mind, that twilio function timeout is 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

we have wrap up of 30s configured and sometimes our agent are getting stuck at wrap-up state. Not sure why they haven't given an option to set up wrap up state out of the box like most contact centers have. Some of the things in twilio flex doesn't make sense.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).